Re installed ubuntu 22.04.4
Ubuntu grub menu 
It shows this menu every time I open my laptop. I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 after accidentally deleting the partition of the OS in disks. After instilling again it shows the menu. I want to know what the "Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) (on /dev/sda3)" means. Finally, I want the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) (on /dev/sda3) to be the default and open without showing the grub menu. Thanks
Update,
So I reinstalled Ubuntu and selected Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS beside Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. The first contains my data when I mistakenly deleted Ubuntu from the disk partition and 2nd is a new one. Now how to remove the one without my old data?
the output of lsblk command


sda3 the 3 rd partition of the first disk.

Did you install into another new partition. As grub shows if two installs and typically just says "ubuntu" for default and then says what partition other installs are in.

can you update your question to include the output of the command lsblk

If you want to save Ubuntu on /dev/sda3, log in with this entry Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (22.04) (on /dev/sda3) from the grub menu and apply this command in the terminal:
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/boot /dev/sda

After grub is installed successfully, open the partition that you don't want to appear in the grub menu, rename /boot directory in this partition to /boot.old, open the terminal, and apply:
sudo update-grub

Open this file /boot/grub/grub.cfg, and you will find two menu entries, Ubuntu and advanced options for Ubuntu. if you want to log in directly to Ubuntu, open this file /etc/default/grub and look at these lines at the first of the file:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5

this may be different but you will set them to these values:
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

Back to the terminal and apply this command again:
sudo update-grub


Thanks to everyone . The problem remained unsolved .  So i reinstalled the Ubuntu . Thanks to everyone for commenting and answering
